# What is the kinetic energy required to impact the surface of asphalt roads?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, civil-engineering

I am trying to find estimates of the minimum kinetic energy required to impact the surface of asphalt roads as a first-order impact assessment of road functionality to rockfall (i.e. boulders hitting the road and creating a hole/crater). What I am really interested in is some sort of fragility function relating the kinetic energy or dynamic pressure with a measure of impact – e.g. probability of "perforation" or hole on the road surface.

I haven't found much on that in the Natural Hazard literature and was wondering if anyone here could suggest any Engineering reference.

Thanks!

Comment: What other literature have you accessed? Bitumen roads are not a natural phenomenon.

Comment: A quick google gives this, there are others,: https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/14680629.2017.1380689

Comment: Thanks Solar Mike. I am not an engineer and am not aware of this literature, hence my question here. And yes I obviously did Google searches. The paper you suggested seems to account for time-averaged parameters to estimate some fatigue, which is not really what I need. Bear in mind, I am aware that what I am trying to estimate is a huge oversimplification of the engineering approach - just a different purpose.